# ajax calendar date validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

i want to validate my ajax calendar so that it can only be set for a minimum of three months from the current days date.

Using asp.net with c# so curious as to how it works.

Here is my code so far:

```
        <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="WarrantyTB" Format="dd/MM/yyyy" PopupButtonID="WarrantyCal"></asp:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:TextBox ID="WarrantyTB" runat="server" MaxLength="10" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if the date you want to validate is called 'myDate', this is how you can check this in your controller/model:

```
if(myDate >= DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3))
{ // Do stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

you will want to use a range validator
here is an example:[ajax calendar extender with range example](http://chakkaradeep.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/aspnet-ajax-calendarextender-and-validation/)

Comment: I may have misunderstood I did not think you wanted to do it in code on submit, I thought you wanted to handle it in the asp.net setup of the controls.

Comment: Well either way is fine, thanks for providing a solution either way